# Rhino Commons and Rhino Mocks Reference Documents?

Tags: documentation, rhino-mocks, rhino-commons

Ok, is it just me, or does there seem to be a lack of (easy to find) reference documentation for Rhino Commons and Rhino Mocks?  My coworkers have started using Rhino Mocks and Rhino Commons (particularly the NHibernate stuff), and I found a few tutorial-ish examples, which were good.  But when I see them making use of a class in their code--let's pick something like Rhino.Commons.NHRepository, for example--I have been having a hard time just finding someplace on the web that tells me what Rhino.Commons.NHRepository is or what it does.  I like to learn by looking at real examples, but using this approach, it's very handy to look at what the full docs are for a class, instead of just the current context.

Similarly, I saw `IaMockedRepository.Expect(...)` being used in some code, but it took me forever to finally find [this page that explains the AAA syntax](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/16/Rhino-Mocks--Arrange-Act-Assert-Syntax.aspx) for Rhino Mocks, which made it clear to me.

I've found the [Ayende.com wiki on Rhino Commons](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Commons.ashx), but that seems to have a number of broken links.  To me, the Rhino libraries seem like a great set of libraries in need of some desperate community help in the documentation area  (Of course, as we all know, documentation is not the forte of most coders, and incomplete docs are all too common).  Does anyone know if this is something in the works, someplace that some volunteer documenters are needed, or is there some great reference docs out there that I have somehow missed to Rhino Mocks and Rhino Commons?

Comment: It's not just you. I ditched Rhino after two months of hands-on with it, due to the same frustrations with documentation and syntax confusion. I ended up going with Moq when I rolled out a mocking framework to our product development team.

Comment: I'm also looking for documentation on Expect - the wiki has nothing. It's a bit crap, tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the official documentation is the wiki you mention. It's an open wiki so if you find any broken links, **please** fix them! Documentation is a great way to contribute to an open source project. So if you find anything missing please add it to the wiki, and everyone will benefit.

That's how open source projects grow, with everyone's contribution.

OTOH, I think most people are used to looking at the project's tests as documentation, maybe that's why the wiki could be outdated/incomplete.

If you have more questions about Rhino Mocks or Rhino Commons, use the [Rhino google group](http://groups.google.com/group/rhino-tools-dev) (over 330 members) or the [Rhino.Mocks group](http://groups.google.com/group/RhinoMocks) (800 members).

Comment: Oooh, the google groups info is good information!  And of course, being new to the Rhino libraries and wiki, I noticed the broken links, but haven't dug far enough to find where they should actually be pointing, yet... ;-)